# How to combine time in an if argument?

Tags: javascript

Right now this code works perfectly fine. When the day is Saturday or Sunday, the button will turn RED. When hours is smaller than 9am and bigger than 5pm, the button will turn RED.

In other words, Monday to Friday 9-5pm the button is GREEN.

How do I make it so on a Friday (today.getDay() == 5), the button is GREEN 9am-4pm. whilst keeping the above statement the same. The business closes early on a Friday, by an hour.

```html
<style>
.onlineStatus {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<span class="onlineStatus" id="onlineStatus"></span> Online

<script>
var div = document.getElementById('onlineStatus');
div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';     
var today = new Date();
var hr = today.getHours();   
if(hr <= 9 && hr >= 17 || today.getDay() == 6 || today.getDay() == 0) div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
</script>
```

Comment: Does it work? I don't think so.

Comment: my code works, just for monday to friday 9-5pm, the button will TURN GREEN.

Comment: I am wondering if it turns red outside the 9am-5pm range?

Comment: yes it does, just tested it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I would set the "ending" hour conditionally.

```
var hr = today.getHours();
var day = today.getDay();   
var maxHour = day === 5 ? 16:17; // there it is

if( (hr <= 9 || hr >= maxHour) || day == 6 || day == 0) div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

It seems more elegant/readable than stacking a lot of conditions.

*You could also rewrite the closed days part (just a suggestion):*

```
var hr = today.getHours();
var day = today.getDay();   
var maxHour = day === 5 ? 16:17; // there it is
var closedDays = [0,6];
var isTodayClosed = closedDays.indexOf(day) > -1;
if( (hr <= 9 || hr >= maxHour) || isTodayClosed) div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Comment: `hr <= 9 && hr >= maxHour` should be `hr <= 9 || hr >= maxHour`. A number cannot be less than 9 and more than 14 at the same time.

Comment: Yes, thank you for noticing it. I simply pasted the original code on this part. I updated this part.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a bit of extra logic in your `if` statement.  You need to find out if it's Friday, and if so, turn red if the hour is after 16.

So the following additional checks would achieve this:

```
(today.getDay() == 5 && hr >= 16)
```

And in your original `if` statement:

```
if(hr <= 9 && hr >= 17 || today.getDay() == 6 || today.getDay() == 0 || (today.getDay() == 5 && hr >= 16)) div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Here's the snippet with this in:

```html
<style>
.onlineStatus {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<span class="onlineStatus" id="onlineStatus"></span> Online

<script>
var div = document.getElementById('onlineStatus');
div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';     
var today = new Date();
var hr = today.getHours();   
if(hr <= 9 && hr >= 17 || today.getDay() == 6 || today.getDay() == 0 || (today.getDay() == 5 && hr >= 16)) div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
</script>
```

Comment: I see, but wouldn't I need to define that FRIDAY is BETWEEN 9 till 4, instead of just stating hr is greater than 16:00

Comment: @UrbanOzzy No because you have already qualified whether it is after 9am with your first check `hr <= 9`.  This will automatically exclude any times before 9am on Friday

Comment: Just realised hr <= 9 has to be hr <=8. For 9 o clock start